# module.js:491 throw err; Error: Cannot find module 'www/node-str/index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, module

I'm with this problem and i'm not able to solve, as far as irealized i did not find any errors, but i'm a beginner, so i do not know much, here is the code:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
module.js:491
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/www/node-str/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**app.js**

```
 const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 const app = express();
 const router = express.Router();


 const index = require('./routes/index');
 const products = require('./routes/products')

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

 app.use('/', index);
 app.use('/products', products);

 module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
 'use strict';

 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();

 router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
 res.status(200).send({ title: "Node Store API", version: "0.0.1" });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSSnY.png)

Comment: Where is located index.js. Show your directory tree

Comment: @YanetPedraza 
ready, I edited the link and put the image at the end, at a glance

Answer (score -1):

Your package.json it is:

```
"main": "src/app.js"
```